# Can you make a profit mining with CPU/GPU?

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, mining-profitability

A Radeon HD 7950 has the following hash rates:

- Around 600 MH/s for Bitcoin
- Around 600 KH/s for Litecoin

I used the profitability calculator at [bitcoinwisdom](https://bitcoinwisdom.com/bitcoin/difficulty) to estimate revenue:

- Bitcoin: 0.06148 USD / Month
- Litecoin: 0.6661 USD / Month

Am I missing something? Less than 1 dollar per month? Is it because of the specialized mining hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No you are not missing anything. [CPU mining has been unprofitable since 2011](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/59/5406), [GPU mining just slightly later](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5608/5406).**

Today, [ASICs](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/12042/5406) rule mining. The Bitcoin network has more than [300 Phash/s](https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate) by now, that is 300,000,000,000 Mhash/s.

The upcoming ASIC miner generation is [announced to provide more than 9,000 Mhash/s per Dollar](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison). Times for GPU/CPU mining are long gone.

The situation is largely the same for Litecoin with a slight delay.

Also see: [Why does mining profitability tend towards zero?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2154/5406)

There might be some altcoins that can still profitably CPU/GPU mined and traded for Bitcoin thereafter, but I am not sure even they are worth when you factor in time investment.