# Would pool mining within video games (to make them free) be profitable?

Tags: mining-pools

Say a big game company like steactivblizzard released the latest Call of Assasins Hitman for free. They could incorporate bitcoin mining within the menu/pause/loading screens as a sort of payment method. Just a small burst of bitcoin mining so as to not interrupt gameplay too much, much like how we used to have loading screens before SSD.

Would this be profitable? I'm thinking that people playing these games are most likely to have high-end GPUs. And these are big ticket games with a lot of players. Would they be able to successfully mine coins to the point of being profitable?

Comment: Bitcoin mining using generic consumer hardware has been non-profitable since about 2013, when the first ASICs appeared. These days, GPU mining won't even gain you enough to compensate for the wear & tear on your hardware, much less enough to pay for the added electricity usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one calculate the profitability of GPU mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5608/how-does-one-calculate-the-profitability-of-gpu-mining) or [Is Gpu mining still an option?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41125/13866) whose answers mention pool mining.